# who is who or creating objects from extended class

Tags: c#, oop

try to understand all power of OOP

create 3 classes

```
class A
{
     public string Foo()
    {
        return "A";
    }
}

class B:A
{

    public string Foo1()
    {
        return "a";
    }
}

class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new B(); //can use method just from a
        B b = new B(); //both
        A aa = new A(); //just from a
        string result = b.Foo();
        string n = ((A)b).Foo().ToString();
    }
}
```

currently try to understand what the difference between A a = new B(); and A a = new A(); - try to use it - can use same method from classes - see pic

[image]

also try to understand what difference beetwen

```
B b = new B();
((A)b).Foo();
```

and

```
A a = new B(); 
b.Foo();
```

and

```
A a =(А) new B(); and A a = new A();
```

Also try to find good tutorial with explanation of main principles of OOP, but still have some question.
thanks all for understanding

Comment: It seems like you just need a general OOP tutorial. Specifically, you're asking about the concept of inheritance.

Comment: The differences will show up when you have methods that are overriden and/or hidden.

Comment: You may find it easier to read this kind of thing if you use real words instead of `A` and `B`. A classic one is `Animal`, and `Cat` and `Dog` which inherit from `Animal`, each of which implement `Speak()` by writing either `Meow` or `Woof` to the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest difference is:

```
A a = new B();
B b = (B) a;  // works!
```

```
A a = new A();
B b = (B) a;  // compiler error
```

**Even if you assign `B` instance into `A`-typed variable it's still an instance of `B` class, so you can cast it back to `B`.**

But that's just a simple example. Real differences pop out when your class have `virtual` methods

```
class A
{
    public virtual void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A : Foo();");
    }
}
```

that are `override`n

```
class B : A
{
    public override void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B : Foo();");
    }
}
```

and/or hidden:

```
class C : A
{
    public new void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("C : Foo();");
    }
}
```

within derived classes. With that class declarations you'll get following results:

```
{
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
    C c = new C();

    a.Foo();  // prints A : Foo();
    b.Foo();  // prints B : Foo();
    c.Foo();  // prints C : Foo();
}

{
    A a = new A();  // prints A : Foo();
    A b = new B();  // prints B : Foo();
    A c = new C();  // prints A : Foo();

    a.Foo();
    b.Foo();
    c.Foo();
}
```

That's much more interesting, isn't it? You should read more about [overriding and hiding methods](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_polymorphism.html) and class inheritance in general..

Comment: thanks - usefull link and comment for me, try on some examples - now situation for me almoust clear, but think much better i will understand it when start to work with it

Answer (score 3):

```
A a = new A();
```

Creates a new instance of `A` and holds it in a `A` variable. You can access all methods and properties of `A`.

```
A b = new B();
```

Creates a new instance of `B` and holds it in a `A` variable. You can only access any methods or properties exposed by `A`.

The difference is this...

```
B c = (B) b;
```

This line will only work if the var `b` was originally instantiated as a `B`, or a child class. Otherwise, it will throw an exception

Comment: and how about `A a =(А) new B();` this - can it be, think it's ok, because B() is instantiated of A()- correct?

Comment: @Kirill, the casting is implicit, there's no reason to make it explicit.

Answer (score 3):

```
Class B is extending from Class A,
```

So **B -- IS A --> A**

```
        A a = new B(); // B IS A --> A, has a reference of A but object of B,
                       // hence can use method just from a
        B b = new B(); // B is an instance of B which is an A, hence both
        A aa = new A(); // A is a super class here, subclass instance cannot access 
                        // so just from a
```

Hope this helps.